# Extending isomorphisms in the semi-simple case.

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, modules, pro-p-groups

Is there some proposition saying how to extend an isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces where $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$ to an isomorphismus of $k[H]$-modules where $H$ is a group of order prime to $p$ ? (This should be some semi-simple case)

My problem arose in the context of Lazard's famous theorem **[1]:**
For a uniformly powerful pro-$p$-group $G$ there is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector spaces.

$$H^i(G,\mathbb{F}_p) \longrightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^i((G/G^p[G,G])^*)$$

Which I like to extend to the case of both sides being $H$-modules.

Thank you! :)

*[1] M. Lazard, Groupes analytiques p-adiques, IHES publ. math. 26 (1965)*

Comment: What is the relation of $H$ to $G$?  It can't be that $G \leq H$ because you imply $H$ is of finite order (when you say it has order prime to $p$), whereas any such $G$ is infinite.

Comment: @mt_ This might be misleading, but they have no direct relation. In the context of arithmetics, $H$ will be the Galois group of an extensetion K/F and $G$ of an extension $L/K$ of $K$. But still, $H$ is finite of order prime to $p$ and $G$ could be infinite.

Comment: It looks like you really don't want to *extend* anything, but rather to conclude that the $k$ isomorphism you already have happens also to be a $k[H]$ isomorphism. That would seem to imply that all $k[H]$ modules with the same $k$ dimension are isomorphic. I'm not familiar with pro-$p$ finite groups, so I'm unable to say whether or not that's feasible, but it sounds unlikely...

Comment: @rschwieb Of course it is unlikely that all $k[H]$-modules of the same $k$-dimension are isomorphic. But here we have in addition that $H$ is of order prime to $p$ and $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, so maybe that is already enough for them to be isomorphic? :)

Comment: Dear @BISHD : Yeah, I can't tell: Beyond the split between finite and infinite groups, I have no intuition for how special group types affect the groupring structure. I will be sure to watch what you guys come up with :)

Comment: well if there's no relation between $H$ and $G$, why not just declare both sides to be trivial $H$-modules so that any linear isomorphism is an $H$-module isomorphism?  There must be some relation....

Comment: @BISHD If you know the explicit isomorphism of the two structures you gave, did you have trouble checking directly that it is $k[H]$ linear?

Comment: Dear @mt_ I'm worried that my idea of trivial module structures isn't the one you're thinking of, so I need to ask: can you please explain "trivial $H$ module"?

Comment: @rschwieb for me, if $k$ is a field, *the* trivial $kH$-module is a one-dimensional vector space on which all elements of $H$ act as $1$, and *a* trivial $kH$-module is one isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of the trivial $kH$-module.

Comment: @mt_ We cannot assume that both modules are trivial $H$-modules. In the above example, $H$ operates via conjugation on the cohomology groups. And via a profinite version of the Schur-Zassenhaus-theorem one would get a non-canonically action of $H$ von $G$ coming from the split sequence $1 \rightarrow G \rightarrow \Lambda \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$, where $\Lambda$ is the Galois group of $L/F$. But I don't know exactly how $H$ operates on the exterior power to be honest!

Comment: @mt_ thank you :) it was indeed different from what I was thinking.

Comment: OK, so there *is* some relation between H and G! I think what you need to do is to understand the definition of Lazard's map so that you can check if it respects the H action. If H acts on V then it acts on $V\wedge V$ by $h \cdot v \wedge w = hv \wedge hw$

Comment: @mt_ Thanks, that action already helped me. I really want to avoid going  into the definition of the map, because it is really complicated and out of my scope at the moment! You don't think, that could be some more general principle saying that the action of this special kind of group does not matter?

Comment: no, any non-trivial group has two non-isomorphic representations of the same dimension, so you have to get information about how $H$ acts somehow.  If it's a specific example you have in mind, you could start by computing the action of $H$ on $G/\Phi(G)$ - if that is trivial then so is the action on the whole right hand side...

Comment: The action of $H$ on the cohomology groups $H^i(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is given via conjugation. Hence the action of $H$ on $H^1(G, \mathbb{F}_p) = (G / \Phi(G)[G,G])^*$ must be conjugation as well.

Comment: @mt_ Could one deduce a lemma like this: If $A,B$ are $H$-modules with the same group action of $H$. Is every homomorphism $A \rightarrow B$ of those modules as abelian groups automatically compatible with the action of $H$, i.e. does every $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism extend to an $H$-homomorphism? Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean for the action of $H$ on two *different* modules to be "the same"?  Certainly if $A \cong B$ then not every homomorphism of abelian groups $A \to B$ will be a module map (this would only be true if $H$ acted trivially on both)